# In C/C++, does left or right shift by ZERO actually generate an instruction?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bit

I am not very familiar with assembly language or disassembly binary codes, could someone tell me, if "x <<= 0;" or "x >>= 0;" will actually generate instructions?

Comment: Why does it matter? (You could just try it and see, but it you're not really into assembly language why do you care?)

Comment: Have you tried compiling with/without, and looking at the code in a debugger to see if the assembly is different?

Comment: You can still tell the difference between putting that statement in or not, if nothing changes then it's an easy conclusion to draw. (I don't see any difference [here](http://goo.gl/hC8IHH) but ymmv)

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980565/will-bit-shift-by-zero-bits-work-correctly

Comment: Since it is a no-op, most probably the intermediate code generated for it (if any) is removed during the code optimization phase, before any assembly code is generated. This should happen on a release build. A debug build probably contains the instruction translated to assembly code but it's still a no-op.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `x` is an integer type, `x >>= 0` and `x <<= 0` should not generate any code.  Yet there are specific circumstances where the compiler could and indeed should generate code:

- If you turn optimizations off (`clang -O0` or `gcc -O0`), the compiler may generate code and in the case of `clang`, will.  But it is not required to.
- If `x` is a `volatile` qualified type, the compiler is **required** to generate code to read its value and write back the value read.  The actual shifting will do nothing to the value, so the code generated may be identical to that generated for `x = x;`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends really on the compiler and which optimizations are on. Nevertheless, GCC seems to consider them as no op even if optimization is `-O0`.

[**Live Demo**](http://goo.gl/IO7iQg)

While CLANG with `-O0` takes them under consideration and generates instructions.

[**Live Demo**](http://goo.gl/QmQ5jN)

Both compilers for `-O1` and above optimize away these instructions.